# Rewrite Rules and Login Issue

Tags: users, login, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I have rewritten the rules in the .htaccess file of my root domain and now it shows exactly the same content as my subdirectory. Important: it is not been redirected to it. 2 seperate sites with different urls show the same content. So domain/page1 shows the same content as domain/subdirectory/page1.

The code that I have added in htaccess of my root domain is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ sub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/$1
```

Issue:

At the Subdirectory everything works properly. A user can login to the backend and from the frontend he can also see the admin bar and specific personalized info.

At my root domain should happen exatly the same but it does not. A user can login only to the backend. In the frontend every logged In user is just a visitor - no admin bar or personalized info is displayed. When a user logs in, he should see the dashboard of the subdirectory but that does not happen. He sees the backend of the root domain but that is useless as any change there would not be visible to the frontend as only content from the subdirectory is displayed.

How could I change that? Does anybody know why is this happening?

Thank you!

Comment: "Important: it is not been redirected to it. 2 seperate sites with different urls show the same content." - Although your root `.htaccess` file would appear to _rewrite_ all requests to the subdirectory - so that would imply you have 1 site (in the subdirectory) - at least only one site that is accessible? However, since you have "one site", accessible from two different URLs (of which only one can be canonical) then I imagine there could well be some kind of conflict. (?)